# Background color change in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have implemented `BottomNavigationView` which is available from the new support library 25.0.0. Here is my code for that

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/text"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/text"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

And `text.xml` drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

With this code I am able to change text color when menu item is clicked, but when I apply same thing to `app:itemBackground` it is showing error `<item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable`.

This is what I have tried for `app:itemBackground`

```
app:itemBackground="@drawable/text"
```

So my question is how can I change the background color of the selected menu item?

Comment: Create a drawable file and set to `app:itemBackground`. According to  [BottomNavvigationView Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#setItemBackgroundResource(int))  You can set only resources as a background .

Comment: try to add
android:drawable="@drawable/item_background_selected" inside your item

Comment: @AnkitaShah yes that is what i have done, i have tried `app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"` which is drawable file only

Comment: If it is drawable then you have to write `app:itemBackground="@drawable/colorPrimary"`.

Comment: @AnkitaShah i have also mentioned it in my question, please check it `but when i apply same thing to app:itemBackground it is showing error`

Comment: @Charuka that is also showing same error

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/item_background_selected"
<item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_enabled="true" />
<item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
</selector>` when you set it like this in your text xml still you get it ?

Comment: @Charuka yes same error

Comment: @Charuka its done, we cannot use android:color for `itemBackground`, we have to use `android:drawable` within '<item>', your answer was partially correct. But we cannot not include `<item>` with `android:color` also, that was generating the error.

Comment: @Ravi Rupareliya cool i was with my mobile otherwise ill give that a better shot :P :))

Comment: Check this manual http://en.proft.me/2017/01/30/android-bottomnavigationview-tutorial-example/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

found an answer from this [medium post](https://medium.com/@Alexey.Rudakovsky/joe-thank-you-for-this-article-2781df22d1e4#.5e6xdqe9c)

1. We need to use `android:state_checked` instead of `android:state_enabled`
2. within `onNavigationItemSelected` you need to use `return true` instead of `return false`.

and to set background, we cannot use `android:color` in `<item>`, we need to use `android:drawable`

So here how it looks xml file when you are setting it for `app:itemTextColor` and `app:itemIconTint`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

and to set `app:itemBackground` selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/banner_white" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/banner_green" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Here `banner_white` and `banner_green` are pngs.

Comment: Will be great if you can add your updated views  xmls  here too for  future

Comment: You can actually use a color resource instead of a drawable, but with an `android:drawable` attribute, like this `android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"`

Answer (score 23):

I encountered a similar problem to the OP's, but a little different. If you put sth like`@color/color_selector` into the BottomNavigationView's `app:itemBackground="___"`. It will cause the view to hide in design panel, and the app to crush when launching. Though it works fine if your just set it to a constant color like `@color/black`.

For a more in-depth explanation, I dug into android api reference. Now I think I have found the answer that can reasonably resolve this problem. (May not accurate.)

The problem is, **what you provide are NOT EXACTLY what they asked for**.

`app:itemIconTint` and `app:itemTextColor` ask for a hex color, while `app:itemBackground` asks for a literally [*Drawable*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html). The `<color>` elements we write in `colors.xml` are [*ColorDrawable*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html). It's derived from *Drawable* so it can feed all three attributes.

However, when you change it to use a selector, things become different. Both hex color and drawable have a corresponding selector. A selector acts like the resource you put in, but the outcome is not the original one. It's more like a single-purpose wrapper. You can't feed a hex color to an attribute who requires a *Drawable*.

The color selector is actually a [*ColorStateList*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html), provides a hex color, resides in `res/color`. You can use only the attribute `android:color` in this file. it will prompt an error if you write `android:drawable`.
The drawable selector is [*StateListDrawable*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html), provides Drawable, resides in `res/drawable`. You should write `android:drawable` here, but there is no error if you write `android:color`.

However `android:color` only provides a hex color that can't be recognized as a *Drawable*, while `app:itemBackground` requires a *Drawable*, so the app is doomed. **(Direct cause)**

Both attribute (`android:color` and `android:drawable`) accept a *ColorDrawable*, here it works just like when you set a constant color.

The solution (and the practice) is:

- Use (and only) `android:drawable` in a `res/drawable/drawable_selector.xml`. Example:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" android:state_checked="true" />
      <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccentDark" />
  </selector>
  ```
- Use `res/color/color_selector.xml` when it needs a hex color (to avoid confusing). Example:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="true"/>
      <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
  </selector>
  ```
- Provide `app:itemBackground` with drawable. Example:

  ```
  <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
      ...
      app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawable_selector"
      app:itemIconTint="@color/color_selector"
      app:itemTextColor="@color/color_selector"
      ... />
  ```

(Worth noting that if you are using Android Studio, its auto-completion feature will tell you what attributes are legal and available, and it doesn't suggest you `android:color` in a selector under `res/drawable`!)

Comment: I had to onNavigationItemSelected you need to use return true instead of return false as per the accepted answer for the state change to happen on item click, when following this ap[roach.

Comment: it says @drawable/drawable_selector not found when building even though it literally autocompleted it for me

Edit: Weirdest thing ever, it's saying "color/primary_bottom_select" is missing even though I pointed it as @drawables

Comment: same problem as @pete. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Try this it is a sample code of navigation item select listener. hope it helps you.

```
 @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
    // update highlighted item in the navigation menu
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    mNavItemId = menuItem.getItemId();

    // allow some time after closing the drawer before performing real navigation
    // so the user can see what is happening
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    mDrawerActionHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        navigate(menuItem.getItemId());
      }
    }, DRAWER_CLOSE_DELAY_MS);
    return true;
  }
```

Alternative solution:

Make a drawable file highlight_color.xml with following contents :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="YOUR HIGHLIGHT COLOR"/>
</shape>
```

Make another drawable file nav_item_drawable.xml with following contents:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/highlight_color" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

Finally add app:itemBackground tag in the NavView :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/activity_main_navigationview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
app:itemTextColor="@color/primary_text"
app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_drawable"
app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer">
```

here the highlight_color.xml file defines a solid color drawable for the background. Later this color drawable is assigned to nav_item_drawable.xml selector.

Try this one.

Comment: I didn't asked for item select code, i was asking about itemSelector from xml.

Comment: by the way he already found the solution :) may be you are adding an additional note :P

Answer (score 2):

first create xml bottom_navigation_items with

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <selector>
            <item
                android:drawable="@color/primary_bottom_select"
                android:state_checked="true" />
            <item
                android:drawable="@color/bottom_navigation"
                android:state_checked="false" />
        </selector>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

second: add `app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottom_navigation_items"`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: You can select the menu item and use ripple effect

Comment: [Add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55329470/edit) information to your answer. On SO code answers have low quality.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way worked for me:

```xml
<BottomNavigationView
...
android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"/>
```

```xml
<style name="CustomTheme">
   <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```