# Change icon / text color in footer similar to youtube APP

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a footer similar to youtube APP. When I click one of the icons in youtube App footer. The icon changes to red.

[youtube snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY6e8.jpg)

What is the best way to implement this? Is there a ways to implement using `<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`
in drawable folder

or I have to implement this programmatically. if so I have to put a lot of conditions. I tried the following.

```
if (homeclicked) {
    ImageView homeImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.homeImage);
    homeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_home_orange);

    TextView homeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.homeText);
    homeText.setTypeface(tf3);
    homeText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orangecolor));
}
else {
    ImageView homeImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.homeImage);
    homeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_home);

    TextView homeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.homeText);
    homeText.setTypeface(tf3);
    homeText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}

homeclicked = !homeclicked;
```

I will have to change other icons in the footer accordingly.

I felt the best way is to use pressed, onfocus in selector method in XML drawable but how to change icon and text color when clicking it.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421553/background-color-change-in-bottomnavigationview

Comment: @NileshRathod: If I am right - this doesn't have text change option. only has background color change.

Comment: to change text change color you need to create custom layout for that

Comment: @NileshRathod: I have tried this different App background color change. it works fine but in the youtube, the background color remains the same the icon color and text color gets changed.

Comment: @NileshRathod: How to do that?

Comment: check out this https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation

Comment: @RAMKUMAR check the lib given by hasan or just ping me on hang out i will send u sample project for custom layout

Comment: About the icon, you don't need different icon files you  can just change the color of the icon using `Drawable.setColorFilter `.

Comment: @hasan_shaikh: Thanks a lot. I used the library. Showing up properly. Thanks!