# Bottom navigationitem color is not changing after giving the default color in stlyes.xml file

Tags: java, android

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

 <color name="colorPrimary">#008F95</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#008F95</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#008F95</color>
```

I changed my app default theme and color to set the color for bottom navigation item when the user selected a particular item. This change is working for datepicker, checkbox, spinner but it's not working for bottom navigation item. After changing the default theme style and color bottom navigation item is white color when the user selected particular item and grey color when not selected. I want to change it into colorPrimary when the item is selected. Earlier it worked, but when I created a new project in the android studio and copied the files from the old project and now it's not working.

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421553/background-color-change-in-bottomnavigationview. Hope it will help!

Comment: i tried this its creating one square around the icon when bottom navigation item is selected

Comment: i want to change the icon and text color like in youtube

Comment: Hi @deepa, could you send me the link youtube?